# What's an alternate to last.fm?

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good, personalisable online radio / music apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/what-are-some-good-personalisable-online-radio-music-apps)

Last.fm disables your free radio after 30 tracks. Then what happens? What else can you listen to on the site for free?
What other alternates do I have for free radio? I tried out blip.fm, but then that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GrooveShark.com](http://GrooveShark.com)

GrooveShark is blocked for me at work, so I don't use it.  It seems really great though, I've tried it from home a bit.  I'm not sure about a limit, if someone knows please edit or add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find some good inspiration by looking a question that was answered not too long ago:

["What are some good, personalisable online radio / music apps?"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/what-are-some-good-personalisable-online-radio-music-apps)

Should be lots of good choices, set up with pros and cons, and already rated.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Pandora.com](http://pandora.com)

There are monthly limits you can hit, but they reset every month.  I believe it is currently 40hrs/month.